# Figuring out the precise location of Earth a certain amount of time ago

Tags: internal-consistency, space-travel, astrophysics

Movement is relative, but I've read that an ex-NASA scientist has quantified the speed of Earth hurtling through space to be 1.3 million mph, using the Cosmic Microwave Background as a frame of reference ([link](https://www.businessinsider.com/earth-screaming-through-space-nasa-animated-video-2019-10?op=1)).

I'm working on a story where a scientist has invented a propulsion method that can reach 20% of the speed of light, and intends to travel to the exact location where Earth was 30 years ago.

I'm aiming for soft sci-fi so a certain amount of handwaving is acceptable, but even then, is it plausible that my scientist would be able to calculate where Earth was in relation to the CMB? What about calculating the exact location of a specific human-scale location on Earth 30 years ago?

As a secondary question, given the velocity and the time frame, how long would it take for the scientist to travel back?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Did an edit to hopefully make the question a bit more targeted.

Comment: It all depends on the specific meaning of the word "exact". How exact do you want the exact location to be? Would plus or minus one light year or so be sufficiently exact? (And the Cosmic Background Radiation fills the entire space. It has no beginning and no end. It do not understand what you mean by a position relative to the CMB; as far as I understand, there is no such thing.)

Comment: @AlexP its awkward to find a concise and readable explanation of what was meant, but there are magic words to search for like '[large scale peculiar velocity field](https://www.nature.com/articles/327210a0)'.

Comment: @StarfishPrime: I understand how one can measure a velocity relative to the frame of reference of the CMB. What I don't understand is how one can define a *position* relative to the CMB.

Comment: @AlexP I guess you've hit on the crux of my question. I'd like my fictional scientist to have a specific place to return to for plot reasons. But if it's impossible to even begin to define what a "specific place" even means when it comes to planetary bodies floating around, that looks like the answer to my question is a resounding "no".

Comment: Again, the word relative is important. When you mention you want to know where the Earth was 30 years ago, ... relative to what? The Earth orbits the Sun & the Sun ( more precisely, the Solar system, orbits the center of the Galaxy. Do you want to know where the Earth was in relation to its secondary orbit - around the center of the galaxy - as a result of its association with the Sun and the solar system?

Comment: @Fred I was assuming that if the CMB is good enough to use as a frame of reference for velocity, that means you can make assumptions about position based on it, but I guess I was wrong...

Comment: To clarify why my fictional scientist needs it: he is convinced that he can find someone's ghost at the exact spot that person died, but he can't find it in the original location on Earth so he assumes that his frame of reference for "exact spot" is incorrect. So the reasoning doesn't need to be fully sane, but it needs to be something that a slightly mad scientist can conceivably think of.

Comment: This would become very difficult to calculate precisely. We travel at about 1000 miles per hour, you will need millisecond time measurement precision for a meter accuracy, even when we leave out galactic movement of the solar system.  https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/how-fast-is-the-earth-mov/ Also "30 years" is not an accurate specification.. are you talking about the siderical year or the tropical year ? One siderical year is 1.00003878 tropical years, a relevant deviation when you need meter-precision over 30 "years".  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=82p-DYgGFjI&t=6s

Comment: Another reference question, what location are you looking for ? Reading the title versus your comments, I wonder if you ask about "the precise location of earth" or a "precise location on Earth", that is on the surface. Your question as it is now would yield the exact *center of the planet*. We may wonder where that spot is, in terms of meter precision. Or maybe you are looking for an exact position *on* the planet ? When that is the case, I'd suggest changing the word "of" in the title to "on". My previous comment refers to "on".

Comment: The CMB is clumpy and uneven and therefore provides a means of spatially orienting oneself, but the means of measuring it with precision are not within our grasp in a way that would be better than say, orienting by the galactic centres of the visible galaxies. Are you sure you want to take that particular frame for measuring?

Comment: @Goodies Both really good questions that deepened my understanding of how ridiculously difficult this is. The time measurement angle is interesting, and adds an extra angle to my story (as per my comment, the scientist is trying to find someone's ghost, so he now needs to find the exact time of death). Re: "precise location of earth" vs "precise location on earth", I think I'd rather go with "of" for now, it's a prerequisite for "on" in any case.

Comment: @EveninginGethsemane I went with that because it seemed the closest thing to an "absolute" frame of reference in a situation where everything is in motion. I think that's why the scientist in the article I referenced above picked the CMB, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an interesting question, and how you approach it can vary. One issue the precision you need. The other is what you consider the rest frame, or reference.

The precision you need is interesting because even determining the location on the earth to very high precision is difficult. For example the Terrestrial Reference Frame which is the center of mass of the earth, and is determined by taking the data from laser ranging to satellites moves around in small but measurable ways that drifts over time.

For the choice of reference frame, I think Astronomers also define a local standard of rest (LSR), and for objects in the solar system that is good enough, but that point is moving with respect to the center of the milky way as the solar system rotates the around galaxy at a  couple of hundred km/s.  The LSR is probably defined as the mean motion of mass as it rotates around the center of mass of the galaxy.

Astronomers can also define a Galactic Standard of Rest, or a Galactic Rest Frame. For example using quasar data there is an International Celestial Reference Frame (ICRF) that astronomers also use. This works because the quasars in galaxies are so far away. Of course those galaxies are also moving....

So in the question saying that the rest frame is defined by the cosmic background radiation, I think the assumption is that it is a snap shot of the distribution of mass at the origin of the big bang. Then by doing the survey the astronomers, essentially got a map of everything. Once you have that map, you have information at very long distances with which to define your reference frame.  This paper on [Plank 2018 results](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1807.06205.pdf) goes on to explain that with this kind of mapping one can obtain the motion of the solar dipole with respect to the cosmic background, and also the movement of the galactic dipole with respect to the cosmic background.

Editing to actually try and answer the question...
I think then the problem becomes a math problem of how well you know the different orbits:  Earth around sun, sun around galaxy etc. This is non trivial over long time periods since it is a multibody problem. So in addition to the movement of the solarsystem and planets with respect to the Cosmic Background Rest Frame there are probably errors with that, depending on the precision you want.   And then several calculations between the different reference frames, since you want to perhaps land on a particular spot on the earth.

As an engineer, if you had the technology, it might be simpler to send a series of probes back and forth, and have them tell you how far your calculations are off. The probe could essentially just use a camera to take pictures of the stars, find the location and them perhaps you could move to the location you want, or refine your calculations to get the accuracy you want.

Comment: Thank you! I think this answer gives me what I need. Or at least it tells me what the gaping holes in my idea are, and gives me an idea of how to massage them to the point where a non-subject matter expert can ignore them and enjoy the story. My scientist is trying to hunt down a ghost, so figuring out the precise moment the person died is going to add some spicy detail. Calculating the location within the frame of reference sounds ridiculously hairy, but I can handwave that away with a series of corrective adjustments my scientist makes as he travels there.